# Rails 3.1: Loading image preview on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, preview

I am trying to build a Rails 3.1 app in which users can preview individual pages of documents or whole documents as a slideshow of pages. Thumb-nailing is not a requirement but the ability to show the image at a size that allows reading is

The documents are generated by me and so I control their format. Hence, if it helps to have individual pages as image files, then that can be done. But if its better to have them as PDF, then that is possible too. At any rate, the documents are all housed on a remote server - a VPS perhaps - and they are pulled for preview based on user selection and/or permissions

And so, I was wondering if anywhere here could make a suggestion for a Gem or a plugin (example: Cooliris?) that I could incorporate. I apologize for not being precise enough. But this is one of those times when I don't enough to even start asking the right question. I don't know, for example, what to do a Google search for or whether I really need to set up a media RSS feed - as Cooliris requires

Thanks in advance
Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth having a look on railscasts by Ryan Bates, there is i great cast in which you crop an image and also incorporate a neat live preview as you are cropping, i'm sure you could refactor it to suit your needs.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised

You may need to sign up to view it, but i can assure you that it well worth it as there are 3 casts per week and over 300 in the archives on many topics.